the dollar sign and the `` are not showing correctly
If I use $15 in the editor sometimes it's showing weird characters. here, I removed the $ to make my answer readable, but if you have high rep you can roll back the edit and I guess you could see it.

MathJax is enabled on the site so that we can write equations using LaTeX.  The dollar sign is the token used for the beginning of an equation.  Just escape the dollar sign using a \ character.

Those are formatting symbols on many Stack Exchange sites. $ begins a section of $\LaTeX$ code, which doesn't work here on meta.cogsci, but it works on the main site. ` begins a section of code-formated text. I've used it on the preceding $ sign, but since it's active here (and on every SE site I've tried it on so far), I won't use it again in this answer. If I did, everything since my first use of the grave accent symbol would appear in code formatting. I've embedded your $ signs in code-formatted sections to prevent them from opening sections of LaTeX code, but if you prefer, you can produce a simple $ with LaTeX following @ChuckSherrington's advice by entering $\$$.
...Actually, I see his advice was even better: just enter \$ for each one!

MathJax is enabled on Bio, CogSci, Stats, Math, MathOverflow, Chemistry, DSP and a couple of others I can't think of offhand.  TeX has their own engine, I think.

They would have their own engine...useful fellows, but so particular!

(curiously enough TeX.SE doesn't seem to render LaTeX at all, so I stand corrected!)

Ha! They're simply too good for it I imagine! More power to 'em :)
